# Chrome crash when Selenium executed SendKeys(Key.Enter)

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have an automation test which has these line of code below, it's for enter searchbox after sendkeys:

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys("@Auto");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

It works perfectly when I run it in debug mode slowly. But without debug mode, Chrome will crash when executed `SendKeys(Keys.Enter)` and Visual Studio shows this message:

```
Message: Test method threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:64847
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

This is the HTML of the element which I got problem

```html
<th class="jss1543 jss1544 jss1534 jss1527 percent-40" scope="col">
    <div class="jss1536">
        <div class="jss1551 jss1552 jss1528">
            <div class="jss1568 jss1555 jss1530 jss1569 jss1556">
                <input aria-invalid="false" class="jss1578 jss1563 jss1531" id="standard-uncontrolled" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

Update the script I'm using:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace AutoKaercher
{
    [TestClass]

    public class CRUD_Languages
    {
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private string intranetURL;
        private string languagesName;
        private string languagesCode;

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Chrome")]
        public void _CRUD_Languages()
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            //Login
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(intranetURL + "/");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("globaladmin");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("1234@Abcd");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/button")).Click();

            //Go to Languages
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/header/div/div/div[1]/span[2]"))).Click();
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/header/nav/div/ul/li[1]"))).Click();

            //Create Languages
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/button"))).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/input")).SendKeys("@Automation Testing");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/input")).SendKeys("@AT");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button[2]")).Click();

            //Check for create Languages successfully
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[1]/div/div"))).Click();
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")));
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys("@Auto");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            //IWebElement searchLanguage = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']"));
            //searchLanguage.SendKeys("@Auto");
            //Actions inputEnter = new Actions(driver);
            //inputEnter.SendKeys(searchLanguage, Keys.Enter);

            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")));
            languagesName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).Text;
            languagesCode = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).Text;
            if (languagesName != "@Automation Testing")
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            if (languagesCode != "@AT")
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }

            //Edit Languages
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/span[1]")).Click();
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/input"))).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/input")).SendKeys("@Automation Testing Edited");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/input")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/input")).SendKeys("@AT-@at");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/button[2]")).Click();

            //Check for edit Languages successfully
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[1]/div/div"))).Click();
            languagesName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).Text;
            languagesCode = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).Text;
            if (languagesName != "@Automation Testing Edited")
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            if (languagesCode != "@AT-@at")
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }

            //Delete Languages
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/span[2]")).Click();
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='intranet-dialog']/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"))).Click();

            //Check for delete Languages successfully
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[1]/div/div"))).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys("@Auto");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).Count != 0)
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }

        }

        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }

        [TestInitialize()]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            intranetURL = "https://rkistage.app.kaercher.com";

            //Open Chrome in Incognito mode
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--incognito");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        }

        [TestCleanup()]
        public void MyTestCleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Chrome version 73.0.3683.86 and ChromeDriver version 73.0.3683.68.

Does anybody have an idea why it happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you for reply. I have add the HTML of the element to my question.

Comment: How does `//*[@id='path']` relates to the HTML you have provided? Can you provide the complete error trace log?

Comment: What is your chrome and chromedriver version? Maybe it's a conflict between them. Check this link: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry for slow reply. I just edited XPath of the HTML. Also, I have provided the full error log above.

Comment: @ToraCode My Chrome's version is 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) and my ChromeDriver's version is 72.0.3626.69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some docs it seems like 72.0.3626.121 is a chromium version that’s not compatible with Chromedriver 72.0.3626.69. As far as I can tell you have two options:

1. Use Chrome version 72.0.3626.81 and leave your chromedriver alone.
2. Keep the browser version you have and use [chromedriver-72.0.3626.121-202.1.x86_64.rpm](https://opensuse.pkgs.org/42.3/opensuse-update-oss/chromedriver-72.0.3626.121-202.1.x86_64.rpm.html)

=========

**The above was not your issue.  Moving on...**

I think I know what's wrong with that line,

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

`Keys.Enter` is from the [`Keys` class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Keys.cs), which, first of all, you have to import (maybe/probably you did already), but more significantly it can only be invoked by [`Actions`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/Actions.cs).  And [here's](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/IKeyboard.cs) the `SendKeys` I *think* you were using. Notice the deprecation warning: `[Obsolete("Use the Actions or ActionBuilder class to simulate keyboard input.")]`.

So anyway, if you try the following, I think it should work.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Keys
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

IWebElement standardUncontrolled = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='standard-uncontrolled']"));
standardUncontrolled.SendKeys("@Auto");


Actions builder = new Actions(driver);        
builder.SendKeys(standardUncontrolled, Keys.Enter).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: I have upgraded my Chrome to version 73.0.3683.86 and use ChromeDriver version 73.0.3683.68 but it seems not working. It still crashes when executed SendKeys(Key.Enter).

Comment: Based on your description that if you debug slowly through it passes, I would highly suspect a timing issue.  I will edit into my answer some thing(s) you can try to make your script work better.

Comment: Thank you alot! I have tried to put `Thread.Sleep(3000);` above that `SendKeys` line but after waiting 3 secs it still crashes.

Comment: @TàiHoàng I'm pretty sure I figured out what is wrong with that line--see the edit I added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @CPeck I really appreciate all the work you have done. I have added your suggested code to my own, but it run through the line `builder.SendKeys(standardUncontrolled, Keys.Enter);` without enter.

Comment: Well shit.  And you're importing both `Keys` and `Interactions`?  The only possibility then brings me back to timing.  Can you share more of your script, ideally the whole thing, pasted in your question?

Comment: @CPeck I have uploaded the full script above. I'm considering this one as a bug between Chrome and ChromeDriver.

Comment: Looks like you haven’t imported the ‘Keys’ class, which I think should be ‘using OpenQA.Selenium.Keys’.  I forgot an important part of Actions, it won’t do anything unless you have .Perform() after specifying what action(s) you want.  Will edit that into my answer.

Comment: @CPeck Hello, I just found out it all about timing like what you said. All your code work perfectly but it is about timing, I have put `Thread.Sleep(1000)` below the `SendKeys(Keys.Enter)` line and it works. I really appreciate what you have done to help me and so sorry for taking your time. Please edit your answer and I will accept it. Thank you once again!